# How to Connect to MySql Rds with SSL Enabled through Spark python?

Tags: python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

How to Connect to MySql Rds with SSL Enabled through Spark python?????

We could able to connect to Mysql RDS with out ssl.

Can Any one tell us what are the configurations need to be done?

Answer (score 0):

This code works for connection to redshift & postgresql. I think it should be the same for mySql as well. Just change the database name to select the correct driver:

```
%pyspark
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd
import psycopg2
sql = "select * from foo limit 10"
df = pd.read_sql(sql,create_engine("postgres://user:password@aws_url:port/database_name?sslmode=require").connect())
df.head(10)
```